# Pandas: Bin and Sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data (in csv form):

```
Country,City,Year,Value1,Value2
Germany,Berlin,2020,9,3
Germany,Berlin,2017,1,4
Germany,Berlin,2011,1,4
Israel,Tel Aviv, 2007,4.5,1
```

I would like to create bins according to the `Year` column such that instead of using the specific year there would be a 5-year-range, and then sum up the values in `Value1`, `Value2`, grouping by the `Country`, `City` and bin ID (in the following example, I called this `YearRange`).

For example, after running this process, the data would look like so:

```
Country,City,YearRange,Value1,Value2
Germany,Berlin,2016-2020,10,7
Germany,Berlin,2011-2015,1,4
Israel,Tel Aviv,2006-2010,4.5,1
```

If this simplifies thigs, I don't mind creating the possible ranges in advance (i.e. I will have a table with all possible ranges: 2016-2020, 2011-2015, 2006-2010, until the earliest date possible in my data).

How can I achieve this using Pandas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @user3483203 I was able to use the cut function to create bins from Year, but then this leaves me with a dataframe of just one column. I need to somehow merge the binned df with the original one and then perform the sum aggregation but I'm not sure how to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `pd.cut` with `groupby`

```
df.groupby([df.Country,df.City,pd.cut(df.Year,[2006,2011,2016,2020]).astype(str)])[['Value1','Value2']].sum().reset_index()
Out[254]: 
   Country      City          Year  Value1  Value2
0  Germany    Berlin  (2006, 2011]     1.0       4
1  Germany    Berlin  (2016, 2020]    10.0       7
2   Israel  Tel Aviv  (2006, 2011]     4.5       1
```