# Pandas - Bin one set of columns and sum the other

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a set of prices and amounts - with amt1 being the total volume for price1.

For me, the prices are too precise and I would like to group/bin/aggregate the prices/amount pairs into evenly spaced buckets based on the price and then summed on the amounts.

For example, my original df:

```
index    price1 price2 price3 price4 amt1 amt2 amt3 amt4
1          451    454    462    470   10    1   2   5
2          448    452    458    464   8     2   6   2
3          461    463    468    480   1     3   6   9
4          453    455    471    481   4     3   2   4
```

Would produce:

```
index bin1 bin2 bin3 bin4 bin5 amt1 amt2 amt3 amt4 amt5
1     440  450  460  470  480   0    11   2    5    0
2     440  450  460  470  480   8     8   2    0    0
3     440  450  460  470  480   0     0  10    0    9
4     440  450  460  470  480   0     7   0    2    4
```

Few things to note:

- I'm choosing to bin in amount of 10.
- The bin1 means 440-449.
- price is always in ascending order.
- I actually have 500 price/volume pairs to calculate (1000 column df) so it needs to scale.
- Speed is actually a priority (though beggars can't be choosers).

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Interesting task. What have you tried so far? For example, what happened when you tried [Pandas: Bin and Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250554/pandas-bin-and-sum)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create flatten DataFrame with groups for distinguish rows by [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) and [`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
a = df.filter(like='price').values.ravel()
b = df.filter(like='amt').values.ravel()
c = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), len(df.filter(like='price').columns))
df = pd.DataFrame({'bin':a, 'amt':b, 'g':c})
print (df)
    bin  amt  g
0   451   10  0
1   454    1  0
2   462    2  0
3   470    5  0
4   448    8  1
5   452    2  1
6   458    6  1
7   464    2  1
8   461    1  2
9   463    3  2
10  468    6  2
11  480    9  2
12  453    4  3
13  455    3  3
14  471    2  3
15  481    4  3
```

Then binning by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) - I try dynamic create labels and bins by floor divide and multiple by `10`, then aggregate by `sum` and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
val = (df['bin'] // 10)
labels = np.arange(val.min() * 10, val.max() * 10 + 10, 10)
bins = np.append(labels, val.max() * 10 + 10)

df = (df.groupby(['g', pd.cut(df['bin'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)])['amt'].sum()
       .unstack(fill_value=0))
print (df)
bin  440  450  460  470  480
g                           
0      0   11    2    5    0
1      8    8    2    0    0
2      0    0   10    0    9
3      0    7    0    2    4
```

Last create exected format of `df` - add new columns by [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) original `df` with renamed columns:

```
cols1 = ['bin{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]
cols2 = ['amt{}'.format(x) for x in range(1, len(df.columns) + 1)]

d1= dict(zip(cols1, df.columns))
d2= dict(zip(df.columns, cols2))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index).assign(**d1).join(df.rename(columns=d2))
print (df1)
   bin1  bin2  bin3  bin4  bin5  amt1  amt2  amt3  amt4  amt5
g                                                            
0   440   450   460   470   480     0    11     2     5     0
1   440   450   460   470   480     8     8     2     0     0
2   440   450   460   470   480     0     0    10     0     9
3   440   450   460   470   480     0     7     0     2     4
```