# Pandas binning and sum using custom bins, on categorical columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I want to change my [source dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2d7R.png) to output df [output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ldo.png). Here i'm creating the load column based on min and max of the load column from the source dataframe and create equally spaced bins based on user input. Then i need to sum all the fees values falling between the load values.

```
source_df = {'opr_date': {0: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 10: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 11: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 12: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 13: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 14: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 15: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 16: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 17: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 18: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 19: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00')}, 'opr_hour': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10, 10: 1, 11: 2, 12: 3, 13: 4, 14: 5, 15: 6, 16: 7, 17: 8, 18: 9, 19: 10}, 'market_region': {0: 'Russia', 1: 'Russia', 2: 'Russia', 3: 'Russia', 4: 'Russia', 5: 'Russia', 6: 'Russia', 7: 'Russia', 8: 'Russia', 9: 'Russia', 10: 'USA', 11: 'USA', 12: 'USA', 13: 'USA', 14: 'USA', 15: 'USA', 16: 'USA', 17: 'USA', 18: 'USA', 19: 'USA'}, 'load': {0: 2606.81, 1: 2606.06, 2: 2579.74, 3: 2534.2, 4: 2496.76, 5: 2436.67, 6: 2351.03, 7: 2262.96, 8: 2164.84, 9: 2130.44, 10: 1380.42, 11: 1364.75, 12: 1346.12, 13: 1343.49, 14: 1320.89, 15: 1271.92, 16: 1261.05, 17: 1263.54, 18: 1284.43, 19: 1374.74}, 'fees': {0: -4.165, 1: -2.665, 2: -1.996, 3: -5.45, 4: -2.773, 5: -3.784, 6: -0.988, 7: -2.894, 8: -2.092, 9: 1.104, 10: -4.165, 11: -2.665, 12: -1.996, 13: -5.45, 14: -2.773, 15: -3.784, 16: -0.988, 17: -2.894, 18: -2.092, 19: 1.104}}


output_df = {'opr_date': {0: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 5: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 6: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 7: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 8: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00'), 9: Timestamp('2022-02-10 00:00:00')}, 'opr_hour': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9, 9: 10}, 'Russia': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: -0.925, 7: -2.894, 8: -21.82, 9: 0.0}, 'USA': {0: -25.64, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 6: 0.0, 7: 0.0, 8: 0.0, 9: 0.0}, 'load': {0: 1261.05, 1: 1395.0, 2: 1592.0, 3: 1663.0, 4: 1797.0, 5: 1931.0, 6: 2065.0, 7: 2199.0, 8: 2333.0, 9: 2606.81}}
```

Right now i'm doing it by using a for loop, I create load bins using

```
bin_size = np.arange(
            start=min_bin_value,
            stop=max_bin_value,
            step=self.bin_size,
            dtype=int,
        )
```

and then i run a for loop to find the fees value for the bins:

```
    market_region_list = df["market_region"].unique().tolist()
    region_fees_values = {}
    for region in market_region_list:
        df_copy = df[df["market_region"] == region]
        fees_value = []
        for i in range(0, len(bin_size) - 1):
            # logger.info(bin_size[i])
            fee_values = df_copy[
                (df_copy["load"].astype(int) >= bin_size[i])
                & (df_copy["load"].astype(int) < bin_size[i + 1])
            ][fees].sum()
            fees_value.append(fee_values)
        region_fees_values[region] = fees_value

    df2= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
                region_fees_values, orient="index"
            ).transpose()
    df2["load"] = pd.Series(bin_size)
```

In the loop i find all the rows between all the load bins and then sum the fees column and transpose the dataframe and attach the load values at the end, so that all the market_regions have same number of rows.

The code is working fine, but it takes quite a lot of time to process big dataframe, I want to use pandas/numpy vectorisation technique to speed up the process. Let me know if you guys have any faster approach to solve this problem.

I found something which you guys might want to look at [Pandas: Bin and Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250554/pandas-bin-and-sum)

Comment: Can you please paste in your df instead of image? Using .to_dict() works well for that.

Comment: @MatthewBorish I have updated the question with the dictionary format of both the output and source df. Have a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I used to solve is using [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and [pd.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) together, instead of using for loop, which reduced the time by 92%.

I created the custom bin using the numpy:

```
bins = np.arange(
            start=min_bin_value,
            stop=max_bin_value,
            step=self.bin_size,
            dtype=int,
        )
```

Then I created a loop for each region and binned the data using pd.cut. And took the sum of fees column after groupby. After that i stored the data in dict format with keys being region and list of fees as values. Created a dataframe and transposed it. and got my desired output_df.

```
market_region_list = source_df["market_region"].unique().tolist()
region_fees_values = {}
for region in market_region_list:
            df_copy = source_df[source_df["market_region"] == region]
            binned_fees_list = self.get_fees_by_bins(df_copy, bins, region)
            region_fees_values[region] = binned_fees_list

output_df= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
        region_fees_values, orient="index"
    ).transpose()
output_df["load"] = pd.Series(bins)



def get_fees_by_bins(self, df, bins, region):
        df_copy = df
        new_df = pd.DataFrame()
        new_df[str(region)] = (
            df_copy["fees"]
            .groupby(pd.cut(df_copy["load"], bins=bins))
            .sum()
        )
        new_df = new_df.reset_index()
        new_df = new_df.drop("load", 1)
        return new_df[str(region)].tolist()
```